# What are these parts of the cheeks or face called?

Tags: single-word-requests

Image source: http://neozeitgeist.tumblr.com/post/15761145451/hope-you-all-are-aware-that-for-my-life-being

[image]

[image]

Do these parts of the cheeks/face have a name? If not, how would you describe a florid face where these areas have gone especially red?

N.B. I'm trying to describe a drunk rather than a cute child.

Comment: To me, the circled areas are what I normally mean by *cheeks*. Underlying them are the *cheekbones*, where "high cheekbones" indicates that the "raised" part of the cheek is nearer the eyes than the mouth.

Comment: I'd call them _erythematous_: abnormally red because of capillary congestion (as in inflammation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are called the *[apples](https://www.google.com/search?q=apples%20of%20cheeks&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb)* of the cheeks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say he has "rosy cheeks"?

Comment: The [cheeks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheek) appears to cover a lot more area than just the bits outlined in the image. Also, I'm trying to describe a drunk; rosy cheeks and prominent cheekbones are too complimentary IMO.

Comment: @coleopterist: In your context, you'd probably be better off describing the drunk as having a ["red-veined **nose**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22red+veined+nose%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). That would convey *unhealthy, damaged* without the positive connotations of red/rosy cheeks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. I haven't come across that term before. I'm currently going with _cauliflower nose_.

Comment: @coleopterist: you may want to post another question for the nose (or research it some more). *Cauliflower nose* refers specifically to shape, not color.

Comment: @coleopterist: Also I see [cauliflower nose](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NHnEMdgKJbIC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=%22cauliflower+nose%22&source=bl&ots=kBblpqSiHB&sig=XQUlbscBBA5b_oZT9NkA1NCSpsU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PdqGULvYGaSd0QXPoYCwBQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22cauliflower%20nose%22&f=false) can be the medical condition ***Rhinophyma** (also called bulb nose)... often called **alcohol nose** in the vernacular and related incorrectly to excessive alcohol consumption.*